# set a default value for the dropdown

Tags: angularjs

This is my Java script code

```
$scope.dateSelection = { 1: 'Today' , 2: 'Yesterday' ,3: 'Last 7 days', 4: 'Last business week (Mon - Fri)' ,   5: 'Last week (Sun - Sat)' , 6: 'This month' ,  7: 'Last month' , 8: 'All time' , 9: 'CUSTOM_DATE',10: 'This week (Sun - Today)',11: 'This week (Mon - Today)' , 12: 'Last week (Sun - Sat)' };
```

This is my HTML code

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in dateSelection track by key" ng-change="getPerformanceData(indexValue)" ng-model="indexValue" >
            </select>
```

I want to set a default value is "3: 'Last 7 days'" for the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve the desired effect just by changing the `HTML` template.

```
<select 
    ng-init="indexValue = '3'"
    ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in dateSelection" 
    ng-model="indexValue" 
    ng-change="getPerformanceData(indexValue)">
</select>
```

You'll notice that I've removed the `track by` expression as it's mostly meant to help Angular internally with array sorting - and this is what was causing your problems as you're using an object and not an array.

I've also set the default value in the `HTML` template, but this can also be done in your controller, it's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

If you can customize your object to the keys would be `string`, then you can initialize by setting value in the controller.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/o6onknj5/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.indexValue = "2";
    $scope.dateSelection = {
      1: 'Today',
      "2": 'Yesterday',
      "3": 'Last 7 days',
      4: 'Last business week (Mon - Fri)',
      5: 'Last week (Sun - Sat)',
      6: 'This month',
      7: 'Last month',
      8: 'All time',
      9: 'CUSTOM_DATE',
      10: 'This week (Sun - Today)',
      11: 'This week (Mon - Today)',
      12: 'Last week (Sun - Sat)'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <select ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in dateSelection" ng-model="indexValue">
    </select>
    {{indexValue}}

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have to change that in string..you can do it simply with index :) I'm not saying that this is a bad approach, but is not the best

Comment: Show in your answer how to do this with an index? Moreover, your `plnkr` does not work. And does not set the default value :)

Comment: Ok. Maybe is not the best. What is the best then?

Comment: What d you mean? I checked my plnkr and is working...hmm

Comment: Please check it again

Comment: Hes condition from `ng-options` is wrong, he just need to change that

Comment: Hes condition from `ng-option`s is `valid`. Why it's wrong?

Comment: I have following error in your `plnkr`. **ReferenceError: System is not defined angular2.min.js:1:18
18:23:23.135 ReferenceError: angular is not defined**

Comment: I see. Check now and if still doesn't work, change angularjs version to 1.5.3 or 1.4.0

Answer (score 2):

I tried this, this is also working

Live Example on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mitra/vfdajgqg/1/)

```
$scope.indexValue = "3";
    $scope.dateSelection = { 1: 'Today', 
 2: 'Yesterday', 
 3: 'Last 7 days',
 4: 'Last business week (Mon - Fri)',
 5: 'Last week (Sun - Sat)',
 6: 'This month',
 7: 'Last month',
 8: 'All time', 
 9: 'CUSTOM_DATE', 
 10: 'This week (Sun - Today)', 
 11: 'This week (Mon - Today)',
 12: 'Last week (Sun - Sat)' };
```

I html file

```
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="indexValue" ng-change="getPerformanceData(indexValue)">
                <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in dateSelection track by key" ng-selected="{{key == indexValue}}" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
            </select>
```

In there without customize our string

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in dateSelection track by key" ng-init="key[2]" ng-change="getPerformanceData(indexValue)" ng-model="indexValue" >
            </select>
```

Using `ng-init` in your html `select` tag, will set a default option

**UPDATE**

I made an example in plnkr. Check this: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jIDb7UsQ6v2giVz2TLHj?p=preview)

Comment: then replace key[2] with your correct value. it will work 100%. you just have to set the right value in `ng-init`

Comment: Cannot set property 'setDefault' of undefined

Comment: it means that the value that you entered in ng-init is undefined

Comment: try: `dateSelection[2]` or `dateSelection[2].value`

Comment: Check my answer, I added something

Comment: You have to change the condition from `ng-options`

Answer (score 0):

See the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <select ng-model="person">
        <option ng-repeat="x in people">{{x.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        //Module declaration
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        //controller declaration
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
            $scope.people = [{name:"Peter"},{name:"Julie"},{name:"Roger"}]; 
            $scope.person = "Julie";
        });
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Hope it solves your problem!